# Neo4j and cypher queries confusion

Tags: neo4j

Need some ideas to convert SQL queries to cypher queries.The owner of the organization wants to know how many orders are taken by each of the manager.

Query:

```
SELECT Manager_name,
Count(Order_id) AS number_of_orders
FROM Manager
INNER JOIN
sOrder ON Manager.Manager_id = sOrder.Manager_id
GROUP BY sOrder.Manager_id;
```

Comment: please show us the query that you have tried. Thanks.

Comment: This is what I tried MATCH<-[:PRODUCT]-(:Order)<-[:PURCHASED]-(c:Customer)RETURN Manager_name.I am new to Neo4j so its been very tough for me

Answer (score 0):

Not knowing all your node/relationship types is very confusing. Guessing you have 3 types of nodes;

- Order
- Customer
- Manager

with 2 types of relationships;

- Purchased
- HasOrder

```
// match all customers c that purchased an order o
MATCH (c:Customer) - [:Purchased] -> (o:Order)
WITH o
// match all the managers that are assigned to the order o
MATCH (m:Manager) - [:HasOrder] -> o
// return the name of the manager and the amount of the orders
return m.name as managerName, count(o)
```

Knowing the information i have, this would be my guess.

There are free courses available on [NEO4J](https://neo4j.com/developer/developer_courses/)